# debugging spark job - specific record/column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using the dataframe write method to write a file in parquet format. The job fails with `java.lang.illegalArgumentException`, but the stack trace does not show the exact record or the field that caused this failure.

Is there a way to add this kind of info to the log (which data could not be converted to Date?), without having to (a) guess or (b) load the data as strings and then write a script to see which of them is not a date?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, Spark does not [currently] natively support that granular level of debugging.

However, you may be able to use some of these ideas.

1) input_file_name() can show the exact file that was used to build the data

2) Custom UDF to try/catch the transformation, logging the problem record(s)

3) Manually filtering out unparseable records

4) Using mode options (permissive, etc)

Potentially relevant talk from Spark Summit East 2017: https://spark-summit.org/east-2017/events/keeping-spark-on-track-productionizing-spark-for-etl/

Mode docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv(scala.collection.Seq)